# LINQ join with top 1 from another table

Tags: c#, linq, join

So the scenario is I have a table of items, and for each item there is a number of comments in another table. I want to get a list of the items with the LATEST comment.

I did this:

```
var res = (from i in db.Item 
           select new
           { 
             ID = i.ID, 
             Name = i.Name,
             Comment = (from c in db.Comment
                        orderby c.Created descending
                        where c.Item == i.ID
                        select new { Message = c.Message }).FirstOrDefault().Message
            });
```

Ok, this gets me the results I want, but it's so SLOW... Please, help me make a join out of this instead!

Thank you!

Comment: Why should a join be faster? Did you analyze the generated SQL and try the difference there? And which LINQ flavor is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var res = db.Item.Join(db.Comment, x=>x.ID, x=>x.ID, (x,y)=>new{x,y})
            .OrderByDescending(a=>a.y.Created)
            .GroupBy(a=>a.x.ID,(key,items)=>items.First())
            .Select(a=> new {
                       a.x.ID,
                       a.x.Name,
                       a.y.Message
                   });
```